# Отследить исчезновение тега

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется такой код:

```
# Пока таблица находится на странице
while True:
  # Ищем таблицу
  if not driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/table'):
    # Если она пропала нажимаем на ссылку и выходим из цикла ожидания
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Ссылка')
    link.click()
    break
  else:
    # Иначе ждем две секунды и проверяем снова, пропала таблица или нет
    time.sleep(2)
```

Хотел воспользоваться функцией `WebDriverWait`, но быстрее оказалось нагородить велосипед, чем разобраться. Проблема на данный момент в том, что когда таблица исчезает возникает ошибка:

*Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-container"]/table"}*

Как безопасно проверить на наличие или отсутствие элемента на странице? И можно ли этот код преобразовать на основе `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример использования `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = ...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # 10 секунд
wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-container"]/table')
    )
)
```

Этот код ждет что элемент видим. Если нужно проверить, что элемент невидим, то нужно воспользоваться другим условием, которое ждем (полный список [в разделе Expected Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)) - `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`.

Если же нужно проверить, что элемента вообще нет в дереве, то для этого случая нет стандартного условия и нужно создать свое. Можно создать условие отрицания и воспользоваться им вместе с `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located`:

```
class opposite_of(object):
  def __init__(self, condition):
    self.condition = condition
  def __call__(self, driver):
    return not self.condition(driver)


wait.until(
    opposite_of(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-container"]/table')
        )
    )
)
```