# Обработка исключения на Селениум

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

мне нужно в Селениуме прописать условие что если элемент не кликабельный, то прекращаем скрипт, как я мог бы это сделать? Я знаю про команду `ElementToBeClicable`, есть ли антоним  у это команды?

Вот код где я хочу это прописать:

```
 try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('back_pagin')
                a_next_page.click()

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Почему `NoSuchElementException` не работает, все потому что как оказалось элемент пагинации после того как код прошелся по всем страницам, никуда не девается, он просто становится некликабельным, но, если это будет полезно, когда все страницы прогружены, и элемент пагинации становится некликабельным, появляется новый `css selector`, а именно `.pages .disabled-arrow`, никак не получается обработать исключения, помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отследить исчезновение тега](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331373/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0) Там про невидимость, но подход тот же - использование собственного обратного условия для `WebDriverWait.until`

Comment: Не совсем подходит ответ, потому что у меня программа не выбивает ошибку, она просто бесконечно прогоняет последнюю страницу.

Comment: Это способ создать антоним для `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: А можете это в ответе оформить, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: если есть ElementToBeClicable то антоним будет ! ElementToBeClicable? чисто догадка))

Comment: Хах, к сожалению нет, это так не работает)

Comment: Ответ будет дубликатом. Правильно это закрыть этот вопрос как дубликат.